# How to get webgraph in apache nutch?

Tags: apache, nutch

I have generated `webgrapgh` db in `apache nutch` using command `'bin/nutch webgraph -segmentDir crawl/segments -webgraphdb crawl/webgraphdb'`.... It generated three folders in crawl/webgraphdb which are inlinks, outlinks and nodes. Each of those folders contained two binary files like data and index. How to get visual web graph in apache nutch? What is the use of web graph?

Comment: Where you able to solve this query? I am still getting binary files. How to get readable inlinks_webgraph & outlinks_webgraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Webgraph is intented to be a step in the **score calculation** based on the link structure (i.e webgraph):

- `webgraph` will generate the data structure for the specified segment/s
- `linkrank` will calculate the score based on the previous structures
- `scoreupdater` will update the score from the webgraph back into the crawldb

Be aware that this program is very CPU/IO intensive and that will ignore the internal links of a website by default.

You could use the `nodedumper` command to get useful data out of the webgraph data, including the actual score of a node and the highest scored inlinks/outlinks. But this is not intented to be visualized, although you could parse the output of this command and generate any visualization that you may need.

That being said, since Nutch 1.11 the plugin `index-links` has been added, which will allow you to index into Solr/ES the inlinks and outlinks of each URL. I've used this plugin indexing into Solr along with the sigmajs library to generate some graph visualizations of the link structure of my crawls, perhaps this could suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!! It was really helpful. We are developing a search engine using nutch and solr. We would like your guidance for our project. Could you please share your contact info...

Comment: After generating webgraphdb containing inlinks, outlinks and nodes. Can you please clearly explain how to generate visual graph using sigmajs? Can you please help us in this?

Comment: Hi @KAP, on closer look the output of the `nodedumper` program doesn't contain the inlinks and outlinks, but sorts the list of URLs using the number of inlinks/outlinks or the score. Meaning it does use the link information but it does not output in a usable way. The plugin should work (which is what I've done) you can reach me: betancourt.jorge at gmail.com.

Comment: Hi @JorgeLuis, I am using the same plugin to index both the inlinks and outlinks for each URL but somehow only the outlinks are getting indexed in SOLR and  not the inlinks. Can you please give me insight if there is any thing else we need to do to get the inlinks indexed?

Comment: Your inlinks come from the same host? What is the value of the `db.ignore.internal.links` property? Also, the `linkdb.ignore.internal.links` property is `true` by default (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/nutch-default.xml#L695-L696) causing Nutch to ignore the links from the same host.

Comment: Would it be possible to share your implementation of a working `schema.xml` or the configuration necessary for nutch? So far, I have enabled the index-links plugin, but this makes the indexing process crash.

Comment: @JorgeLuis I'm trying to use the `index-links` plugin, but the indexing stops with the exception "unknown field 'outlinks' " when calling Solr. Where can I find the exact list of the fields used by the plugin which I need to index on Solr ?

Comment: @vortex.alex you need to define 2 different fields in Solr (`outlinks` and `inlinks`) this should be multivalued fields, because usually you'll have several outlinks/inlinks. But, considering your comment, I'm going to add a README file. I'm always in favor of having better documentation.